# As X is changing, so is/does Y

Tags: american-english

I recently read:

As X is changing, so does the need to do Y.

I would have thought that it has to be is changing -> so is, or changes -> so does. But since I've read this at a (presumably) native English source, I just wanted to know whether it is actually possible to say it like that?

Comment: It depends on how **as** is being used. If it is a general statement, I would say "As (when) X **changes**, so does the need to do Y." If it is a particular statement, I would say "As (because) X is changing, so does the need for Y." So I don't think it flows naturally.

Comment: Please gived linked and attributed quotes to enable contributors to judge authenticity and general standards for themselves. Many native Anglophones get less than perfect marks in exams. // That said, this sounds sub-optimal.

Comment: Why do you think that there must be parallelism? What is wrong with mixing the two forms?